# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets with formula to differentiate similar data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

## Make each duplication of a name the same color.

This is what I'm trying to achieve through conditional formatting in a Google Sheets using a formula:
[screenshot of wanted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUj5q.png)

In tab one of [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10z0yHrn94a2TqmMD3fcesxFx8zNli204q7DTAUptZI4/edit#gid=1848789867](https://stackoverflow.com) is the **raw data** and the **example** of what I want Column C to look like (which i did manually).

In tab two [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10z0yHrn94a2TqmMD3fcesxFx8zNli204q7DTAUptZI4/edit#gid=1576950665](https://stackoverflow.com) is **how far I got** with an answer I found on StackOverflow using *=if(C2<>"",ArrayFormula(countif(left($C$2:$C$14,4),left(C2,4)))>2)*

**My remaining questions are**:

- but how do I get the Kirbys to be one color, and the Jennas a different color, and the Kits a third color?
- but how do I get the Kendrickss to be its own color, and the Jamesons yet another different color?
- and what if I had 60 different names instead of 6 different names? Isn't there a formula to format each unique name differently without 60 different conditions set?

Thank you! Arlen

*I tried using AI bots, but nothing they gave me worked, like*
Certainly! To achieve highlighting different names with different colors, you can use the following custom formula for conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100, A1)>1
```

This formula checks if the count of occurrences of the name in column A is greater than 1. However, for highlighting different names with different colors, you'll need a slightly modified formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100, A1)>1
```

This formula counts the occurrences of the specific name in the range and applies formatting if there's more than one instance. Just make sure to apply this formula to the range where you want the formatting to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Helper Column Solution

The solution relies on a dynamic helper column that will place numbers in rows that match duplicated values and those numbers will increment for each unique name.  So first group of duplicates is 1, second group is 2, third group is 3, etc.  These numbers are merely IDs to key off for colors and don't reflect the number of duplicates in a particular group. The order is based on sorting the groups alphabetically.

You will need a single formula but one conditional formatting rule for each unique **color** (not necessarily each unique name as you can choose to double-up or triple-up etc.  Will start to get hard to tell colors apart anyway as the number of colors grows.

There are two approaches below based on where the helper column is located:

1. The Helper Column is located in the **same sheet** as the names to be checked
2. The Helper Column and the names to be checked are in **different sheets**.

---

## Approach 1

## Helper Column in the Same Sheet

If you create the helper column in the same sheet as the values to color, it is simpler and the rule avoids using INDIRECT.

To make it show nicely in the screenshot that follows, I put it in Column D, but you could put it in any column you want.

### Formula in `D1`

```
=LET(rng,C:C, 
   n,TOCOL(rng, 1), u,UNIQUE(n),
   dups,SORT(QUERY({u, ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(n, u))},
     "select Col1 where Col2 > 1", 0)),
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(n, 
     {dups, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dups))}, 2, 0))))
```

<sup>[image]</sup>

### Conditional Formatting Rules

Based on the location of my helper column formula in `D1` your conditional formatting rules would follow the same pattern:

1. **Apply to Range** is always `C:C`
2. **Custom Formula is**

   ```
   =D1=n
   ```

   - `n=number` that's incremented +1 for each color

   1. **First Color**

      ```
      =D1=1
      ```
   2. **Second Color**

      ```
      =D1=2
      ```
   3. **Third Color**

      ```
      =D1=3
      ```
   4. **And so on,** incrementing `n` enough times that you account for the number of groups you want colored. You can also reuse colors if it gets out of hand. For example,

      ```
      =OR(D1=1, D1=10)
      ```

<sup>[image]</sup>

---

## Approach 2

## Helper Column in a Different Sheet

If you create the helper column in a different sheet use INDEX and INDIRECT to check the values.

In this example, the formula/helper column is in `Sheet2`, and the data to format is in `'raw data'`.  The only change needed to the formula is to update the reference `C:C` to include the sheet name `'raw data'!C:C`.

### Formula in `Sheet2!A1`

```
=LET(rng,'raw data'!C:C, 
   n,TOCOL(rng, 1), u,UNIQUE(n),
   dups,SORT(QUERY({u, ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(n, u))},
     "select Col1 where Col2 > 1", 0)),
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(n, 
     {dups, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dups))}, 2,v0))))
```

<sup>[image]</sup>

### Conditional Formatting Rules

Based on the location of my helper column formula in `Sheet2!A1` the conditional formatting rules would follow the following pattern:

1. **Apply to Range** is always `C:C`
2. **Custom Formula:**

   ```
   =INDEX(INDIRECT(sheetName&range),ROW(C1))=n
   ```

   - `sheetname&range="'Sheet2'!A:A"` *(in this example)*
   - `n=number` that's incremented +1 for each color

   1. **First Color**

      ```
      =INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),ROW(C1))=1
      ```
   2. **Second Color**

      ```
      =INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),ROW(C1))=2
      ```
   3. **Third Color**

      ```
      =INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),ROW(C1))=3
      ```
   4. **And so on,** incrementing `n` enough times that you account for the number of groups you want colored. You can also reuse colors if it gets out of hand. For example,

      ```
      =OR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),ROW(C1))=1,
          INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),ROW(C1))=10)
      ```

<sup>[image]</sup>